# jQuery on() instead of live() not working

Tags: jquery

I have the following html tag

```
<input type="text" id="txtColor" />
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="someDynamicElement"></div>
</div>
```

When i do this it works

```
$('#txtColor').live('change',function(){
    var x = this.value;
    $('#someDynamicElement').css('color',x);
});
```

But when i try to do the same using `on()` instead of `live()` as in the below code, it doesn't work. What am i doing wrong

```
$('#wrapper').on('change','#txtColor',function(){
    var x = this.value;
    $('#someDynamicElement').css('color',x);
});
```

Where `#someDynamicElement` is an element that is dynamically added to the page.

Comment: Works for me http://jsfiddle.net/skram/c7Eza/

Comment: Have you loaded jQuery 1.7? `on` is only available as of version 1.7.

Comment: Yes i have 1.7. $(this).val() is my case is being applied to an element that is dynamically added. Unlike the jsfiddle example that SKS posted.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow you. If someDynamicElement is the element being added at some later point, why not just use click() on txtColor if txtColor is there at load time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be calling the code when the element with `wrapper` ID is not accessible (eg. you do not wait for the DOM to be ready).

Try solving this like that:

```
$(function(){
    $('#wrapper').on('change','#txtColor',function(){
        var x = this.value;
        $('#someDynamicElement').css('color',x);
    });
});
```

It will attach `change` event handler to the `#wrapper` element when the DOM is ready.

Other possibilities (some of which others mentioned):

- `#txtColor` is not within `#wrapper`,
- `#wrapper` is added dynamically,
- IDs may be duplicated (both `wrapper` and `txtColor` IDs must be unique, meaning they can be assigned to only one element),

Comment: The OP wants to delegate to the `#wrapper` element. Why are you suggesting that he should delegate to the `document` object?

Comment: document works. But why doesn't it work when i have '#wrapper' instead of document. Is there any performance drawbacks to having document instead of wrapper.

Comment: There is no need to use document over wrapper. Wrapper should be fine.

Comment: @Pinkie: Yes, there are - you may listen for a lot more events than in case of `#wrapper`. So try to narrow the `#wrapper` as much as possible.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas: I have misunderstood the problem OP was facing, will correct it now.

Comment: @Pinkie: Try current solution. I apologize for my mistake. A lot of people spotted the mistake and wanted to share their findings :)

Comment: @Šime i think you are right. The dynamically generated element is inside `#wrapper` but `#txtColor` itself is not.

Answer (score 18):

The reason it's not working is that when you change from `live()` to `on()` you need to change the element you set the listener on to the document element. Try this:

```
$(document).on('change','#txtColor',function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: If a `change` event fires at an ancestor of the wrapper element, then that event will also fire at the wrapper element itself. This is called event bubbling.

Comment: So do i use document for all my on() events.

Comment: @Pinkie, use the document element wherever you would have used `live()` or `delegate()`. Where you would have used `bind()`, then move the selector to where you would have document. For example, the above would become `$('#txtColor').on('change', function(){...})`.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas this is true, but unfortunately doesn't explain why Pinkie was having problems. Using the document element is safer for old `live()` style event handlers because it will receive all the bubbled events.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that both `#txtColor` and `#wrapper` are dynamically appended to the web-page. So, they are included later, *after* the jQuery code executes. At the time when that jQuery code executes, there (still) is no `#wrapper` element on the page...

Did I guess correctly?

Comment: Your comment in Tadeck's answer is the corrent answer. My question was misleading and i corrected the html markup. `txtColor` is indeed outside `#wrapper`. `#someDynamicElement` is what's inside wrapper. so i'm guessing that is why on() was not working on the wrapper level.

Comment: @Pinkie Yes, for `.on()` to work, one has to bind at an ancestor element.

Answer (score 0):

It is very nice to see how you would like to help but sometimes "I guess" or "other possibilities" just confuse everyone, including me. Very appreciated Vega's jsfiddle link however not that helpfull but let's take it from him and there :-) if you put all code from Pinkie inside his jsfiddler link and update just this line

```
<div id="someDynamicElement">What a day?</div>
```

You will see it works perfectly fine *(change content of textbox to e.g red, or green and click outside)* with the **live()** option. However it is not working with **on()**. To fix it we have got two **surprisingly** simple options:

1) just move input inside the wrapper, no change in Pinkie's on() needed, or

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <input type="text" id="txtColor" />
    <div id="someDynamicElement">What a day?</div>
</div>
```

2) keep the html untouched and update jquery as this *(I removed 2nd parameter from on() and changed selector #wrapper to #txtColor)*.

```
$('#txtColor').on('change',function(){
    var x = this.value;
    $('#someDynamicElement').css('color',x);
});
```

Problem fixed, £10,000 cheque received :-)

And if you keep reading till here I am going to guess as well :-) The problem you experienced is just a confusion of how on() works and its selectors. We have got a few options using selectors in on() as you can see actually also here [api.jquery.com/on/](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

And one more bit, please, let's try coding first before guessing the answers :-) unless you are Guru what I am not. Also, let's try to keep the original code untouched as much as possible so the questioner doesn't get confused coz what is very obvious for you could be very confusing for less experienced coders :-)

Good day to you everyone, let's code another day :-)

p.s. one more tip, if you haven't ever used jsfiddle and you manage to update html and javascript you need to click Update or Run at the top menu :-)